# Facebook PHP SDK v5 - AccessToken expiration date

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have two PHP files for making a login-link and receiving the access token (callback). My problem is, I cannot receive or get the expiration date of the access token.

This is my script for creating a link:

```
<?php
session_start();

define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', __DIR__ . '/facebook/');      
require_once __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook( array('app_id' => 'XX', 'app_secret' => 'XX', 'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'));

$permissions = ['email', 'user_likes', 'user_birthday', 'manage_pages ', 'user_photos', 'publish_actions', 'publish_pages' ];

$helper = $fb -> getRedirectLoginHelper();
$loginUrl = $helper -> getLoginUrl('blabla/facebook-login-callback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>'; ?>
```

**This works fine**, my callback file is called.

```
<?php

session_start();

define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', __DIR__ . '/facebook/');
require __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(['app_id' => 'XX', 'app_secret' => 'XX', 'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5']);
$helper = $fb -> getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {

    try {
        $accessToken = $helper -> getAccessToken();

        $isexpired = $accessToken -> isExpired();
        $expiresAt = $accessToken -> getExpiresAt();

        echo "AccessToken: ";
        echo $accessToken -> getValue();

        echo "<br/>ExpiresAt: ";
        echo $expiresAt;

        echo "<br/>IsExpired: ";
        echo $isexpired;

        die();

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // There was an error communicating with Graph
        echo $e -> getMessage();
        exit ;
    }
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e -> getMessage();
    exit ;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e -> getMessage();
    exit ;
} ?>
```

BUT now my problem is, that I DONT get the expiration date as well as the 'isExpired' value, its just empty. The only thing I get is the access token as a string (by 'getValue()').

Can somebody help me? I think my code should be correct?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Thank you, but I need this not manually but programmaticly ..

Comment: I meant you should compare the token debug information from the debug tool to what you get in your script …

Answer (score 0):

**Code**:

```
{
    $accessToken =$helper->getAccessToken();

    $isexpired = $accessToken -> isExpired();
    $expiry_status=json_encode($isexpired);

    $expiresAt = $accessToken -> getExpiresAt();
    $mydate=json_encode($expiresAt);


    echo "AccessToken: ";
    echo $accessToken -> getValue();

    echo "<br/>ExpiresAt: ";
    echo $expiresAt->date;

    echo "<br/>IsExpired: ";
    echo $expiry_status;

    die();
}
```